# Bubble sort not swapping elements of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, bubble-sort

I am creating a simple program that should utilize the bubble sort algorithm to sort a list of numbers in ascending order.

Just for testing purposes I have added the line `alert(unsortedNumbers);`and as you can see if you run it, the numbers do not change order no matter how many passes the algorithm does.

The program seems to be stuck in an infinite loop, as 'Another pass' is printed to the console repeatedly. As instructed by this line `console.log("Another pass");`

As with the bubble sort algorithm, once it does not have to swap any terms on a certain pass, we know this is the sorted list, I have created the variable `swapped`, however it looks like this is always *1*. I think this may be caused by the `swapArrayElements()` function not swapping the terms.

Why is the function not swapping the index of the terms within the array?

*(Code does't seem to run properly on SO's code snippet tool, may have to copy into notepad document)*

```js
function main(){

  var unsortedNumbers =[7,8,13,1,6,9,43,80]; //Declares unsorted numbers array
  alert(unsortedNumbers);
  var swapped = 0;
  var len = unsortedNumbers.length;

  function swapArrayElements(index_a, index_b) { //swaps swapArrayElements[i] with swapArrayElements[ii]
    var temp = unsortedNumbers[index_a];
    unsortedNumbers[index_a] = unsortedNumbers[index_b];
    unsortedNumbers[index_b] = temp;
  }

  function finish(){
    alert(unsortedNumbers);
  }

  function mainBody(){
    for(var i =0;i<len;i++){
      var ii =(i+1);
      if (unsortedNumbers[i]>unsortedNumbers[ii]){
        console.log("Swap elements");
        swapArrayElements(i,ii);
        swapped=1; // Variable 'swapped' used to check whether or not a swap has been made in each pass
      }
      if (ii = len){
        if (swapped = 1){ // if a swap has been made, runs the main body again
          console.log("Another pass");
          alert(unsortedNumbers); //Added for debugging
          swapped=0;
          mainBody();
        }else{
          console.log("Finish");
          finish();
        }
      }
    }
  }



  mainBody();
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
</body>
```

Comment: You have error in your code `if (ii = len){` and `if (swapped = 1){` it should be double equal.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for spotting this, can you write this as an answer and I'll mark as best answer.

Comment: @TobyCannon i think there is more simple ways to do the bubblesort.. don't know if it will fit your needs .. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/26/computer-science-in-javascript-bubble-sort/

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Thanks for that link Joel, certainly looks a more efficient way of doing it! This was just a first revision to try and get the logic behind it, I will not work on more efficient methods of writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
if (ii = len) {
```

and also

```
if (swapped = 1){
```

it should be double equal

Answer (score 1):

Invalid condition check causing infinite loop:

`if (ii = len)` & `if (swapped = 1)` should have `==` or `===` operator. This is causing infinity loop.

> **NOTE:** Your code is not appropriate as per the best practices to avoid global variables. You should not use global variables and try
>   passing variables and returning them back after processing.

Refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zxt0wfxn/) for avoiding globals.